# Vine-style video playback in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, video

I'm looking for a vine-style video playback control for iOS. Meaning, once the video contained in an tableviewcell appears, it's automatically played back without an annoying separate modal popping up on the iPhone. Does anything like that exist already or should I code it myself?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to code it yourself. I implemented this just a few days ago and it was a bit of a pain. What I did was first make sure each video is a screen height apart from the next (tableview cell height should be screen height). Then, in my autoplay method, I look at all the visible cells and check whether the bottom left point for the frame for the video player is on screen. If it is, then play the video in that cell. Here's some sample code. The annoying thing that might need tweaking is the point detection.

UPDATE: Removed old code which was glitchy. Instructions for new implementation work much better.

First, keep track of the cells which are playing with a mutable array: playingCells

Here's the gist of my autoplay method:

- loop through the tableview's visible cells
- for each cell check if the bottom left point of the frame you're adding your AVPlayerLayer to is on screen
- if the point is on screen:
  stop playing all videos in playingCells except the one with the point on screen (stop playing method below)
  add the cell to a mutable array (ivar) to keep track of which cells are playing
  play the video
  break the loop to prevent any other visible cells from playing

The method to stopping videos goes like this:

- loop through playingCells
- if the cell is not equal to the currently playing cell (passed in as a parameter during the call from autoplay) set AVPlayerLayer and AVPlayer to nil

Comment: how did you handle the performance issues which arise when scrolling the feed?

Comment: You noticed that in Vine videos start to play while the tableview is scrolling (Instagram waits for the scroll to stop and only after that it plays the video). The problem is that AVPlayer, for a brief moment, blocks the main thread when it starts the video. This results into lack of smoothness when scrolling through the tableview. So I was thinking you also found a solution to this problem.

Comment: I notice a bit of a hitch in Vine's app when videos start playing as well...I think the trick to doing it their way is to only call the autoplay method when the scrollView is decelerating and to also cache your videos so they load quickly and don't halt the main thread for too long. I went with Instagram's method where it autoplays after the scrollview stops, but I didn't realize Vine did it differently until you pointed it out.

Comment: @AlexTau Did **you** eventually find a fix for this? I'm having the same issue, where the UI-thread is blocked when calling `[AVPlayer replaceCurrentItem...]` (or by creating a new AVPlayer each time). It really annoys me, and I have also temporarily fixed it by only replacing/creating the item when the scroll has stopped..

Comment: What about MPMoviePlayer? Using this will make any performance issues?

Comment: Hello @VikasShah i need your help. Can you please provide me the code.